# React Native Custom UI Component using Library

Tags: android, android-activity, react-native

I've developed an android library which exposes some activities, include one named `AuthenticiateActivity` and also included some helper classes.

I have a second android project that pulls in this library. I am trying create a custom React Native UI component to be able to display the `AuthenticateActivity` using javascript.

I have followed as best I can the documentation on creating native UI components [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html), however my use case is slightly different. As I understand, I need to create a `ViewManager` that extends `SimpleViewManager`, however, the `SimpleViewManager` takes a custom view class as a generic parameter. In my case I'm simply trying to display the activity defined in the library, I'm not looking to create a fully custom `View` implementation.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying a completely new `Activity` you should just use a native module.

There's a [good example](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult) that shows how to wrap a custom `Activity`.